# Scanner cleared during loop: how do I still maintain a certain condition?

Tags: loops, for-loop, math, java.util.scanner

I am in the process of making a program which will display 3 problems of operation type which a user picks. I've used a loop to keep the program generating random numbers for each iteration as well as to display another problem. The problem I'm having is in trying to clear the scanner after taking user input as to not keep the wrong value stored and screw up the loop. I need the one value ("a") to be stored so that the loop continues with the next question. For this post I've taken out all options but addition just for debugging purposes. My code I will paste below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

    Random randGen = new Random(Config.RANDOM_SEED);

    // Welcome
    System.out.println("Hello and welcome to the Math Trainer!\n======================================");
    System.out.println("Which math operation would you like to practice?");

    // Create a counter for correct answers
    int correctCount = 0;

    // Create a for loop to generate multiple questions
    for (int count = 0; count < Config.NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS; count++) {

        // Calculate random values from seed and shift them within range
        int ran1 = randGen.nextInt(Config.MAX_VALUE - Config.MIN_VALUE + 1);
        int ran2 = randGen.nextInt(Config.MAX_VALUE - Config.MIN_VALUE + 1);
        int ran1Shift = ran1 + Config.MIN_VALUE;
        int ran2Shift = ran2 + Config.MIN_VALUE;

        // Initialize different answers per operation
        double additionAnswer = (double) ran1Shift + ran2Shift;
        double subtractionAnswer = (double) ran1Shift - ran2Shift;
        double multiplicationAnswer = (double) ran1Shift * ran2Shift;
        double divisionAnswer = (double) ran1Shift / ran2Shift;
        double remainderAnswer = (double) ran1Shift % ran2Shift;

        // Ask for user input on which to choose (only on first run of loop)
        if (count == 0) {
            System.out.println("    " + "[A]ddition");
            System.out.println("    " + "[S]ubtraction");
            System.out.println("    " + "[M]ultiplication");
            System.out.println("    " + "[D]ivision");
            System.out.println("    " + "[R]emainder");
            System.out.print("Enter your choice:" + " ");
        }   


        // Presentation of addition problems
        if (stdin.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
            System.out.print(
                    "What is the solution to the problem:" + " " + ran1Shift + " " + "+" + " " + ran2Shift + " = ");
            if (stdin.hasNextDouble()) {
                double userNum = stdin.nextDouble();
                stdin.nextLine();
                if (userNum == additionAnswer) {
                    System.out.println("That is correct!");
                    correctCount++;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("The correct solution is: " + additionAnswer + ".");
                }
            } else {
                stdin.nextLine();
                System.out.println("All solutions must be entered as decimal numbers.");
                System.out.println("The correct solution is " + additionAnswer + ".");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("I'm sorry, I only understand choices of: A, S, M, D, or R!");
            count--;
        }
    }

    // Program exit
    System.out.println("*** You answered " + correctCount + " out of 3 questions correctly. ");
    System.out.println("======================================");
    System.out.println("Thank you for using the Math Trainer!");
}
```

`}`

The output I get if I enter the correct answer to the first problem (13) is: 
https://gyazo.com/773f9be3b51f51f5086f38f36ed0c86b

In which I have to enter "a" again for the next question to show.

The output I should get is here:

https://gyazo.com/6609a9f0b44d0b446439d3331be51eb9

Please let me know if you have any questions and thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (stdin.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("a"))` this is the cause of your problem.
For a quick fix, move the codes asking for `operationType` to outside of the loop since it's only executed once.

```
    System.out.println("    " + "[A]ddition");
    System.out.println("    " + "[S]ubtraction");
    System.out.println("    " + "[M]ultiplication");
    System.out.println("    " + "[D]ivision");
    System.out.println("    " + "[R]emainder");
    System.out.print("Enter your choice:" + " ");

    String operationType = stdin.nextLine();

    for (int count = 0; count < Config.NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS; count++) {
        //codes
        if (operationType.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
```

Might be better to use a switch statement for checking the operationType too.

Comment: I'm not sure that that solves the issue. If I enter the correct answer for the problem it presents, the scanner is still cleared and will not store my choice of "a" for the next time around

Comment: If I create a loop within the "a" if statement then it saves the value, however, since the random values are generated outside of that, I end up with the same values over again.

Comment: The only solution I can seem to find is if I put the random number generator inside the loop which is inside the if "a" statement. This seems repetitive though since I have other operations which will need the same procedure

Comment: Not sure if you applied my suggestion correctly...`operationType` should remain in memory for the entire run-time based on the above code, as it is created outside the loop.